# ActionListener on marker in MapContainer is not triggered in simulator (Codename One)

Tags: codenameone

My Codename One app features a MapContainer, which displays some markers. When the user clicks on a marker a new form with some details about the markers should be shown. Here is the code I use :

```
currentMap.addMarker(reportIcon,
                    new Coord(report.getReportLocation().getLatitude(), report.getReportLocation().getLongitude()
                    ),
                    report.getReportCategory().getCategoryName(), "",
                    (evt) -> {
                        System.err.println("You've clicked on a marker");
                        // Opens the details 
                        new DetailsForm(theme).show();
                    });
```

However neither the message in the console nor the DetailsForm is shown when I test it in the simulator.

Did I make a mistake or it is the behaviour to expect in the simulator and it will work correctly on a real device ?

Any hint appreciated!

**EDIT 2017-02-14:**
If I zoom enough by double clicking on the map (since the plus/minus buttons do not seem to work on my simulator), and add `.show()` to the `new DetailsForm(theme)` that I forgot, then the form is shown as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the `MapComponent` fallback in the simulator or the new JavaScript fallback? If the latter then it's still under development and most methods don't work yet.

I just tried the test app and marker clicked is invoked.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am using MapContainer which states `An abstract Map API that encapsulates the device native map and seamlessly replaces
 it with MapComponent when unsupported by the platform.`. So I guess MapComponent is used since I did not change anything proactively!

Comment: Sorry my bad, it works! I had to double click on the map to zoom enough (the plus / minus map buttons don't seem to work) to separate the different markers, and then if I click on a marker it shows up (I also forgot to add `.show()` ). Anyway thanks for your answer @Shai!